# How do I generate a random RDD in Java Spark

Tags: java, random, apache-spark

Basically I want something like this,

```
int count = 100;
Java<String> myRandomRDD = generate(count, new Function<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String call(String arg0) throws Exception {
            return RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(42);
        }
    });
```

Theoretically I could use Spark `RandomRDD`, but I can't get it working right.  I'm overwhelmed by the choices.  Should I use `RandomRDDs::randomRDD` or `RandomRDDs::randomRDDVector`?  Or should I use `RandomVectorRDD`?

I have tried the following, but I can't even get the syntax to be correct.

```
    RandomRDDs.randomRDD(jsc, new RandomDataGenerator<String>() {

        @Override
        public void setSeed(long arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public org.apache.spark.mllib.random.RandomDataGenerator<String> copy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String nextValue() {
            RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(42);
        }
    }, count, ??);
```

The documentation is sparse, I'm confused, and I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Mind if I ask what this is for? Since if its for testing scalacheck based approach might be better (but otherwise we can dig into using RandomRDD).

Comment: I'm generating a broadcast variable and trying to tune Driver Memory and spark.driver.maxResultSize.  So the best approach I see is to generate a representative RDD then call collect, and see if I get a Java Heap Error or an OutOfMemoryError.  Otherwise I have to wait 8 hours for the broadcast variable to be populated from 1 month of data.

Comment: Ah ok then, sounds like using RandomRDD would be a good use case then.

Comment: or wait, actually I don't think I fully understood what you are trying to do. I mean calling collect. Whats the broadcast variable for? Calling collect() brings all of the data back to the driver program, so you will naturally run into a point where it doesn't fit in memory anymore.

Comment: I'm trying to tune the job for a month of data.  I don't want to set the driver memory and the spark.driver.maxResultSize to 20gb.  I want configurations that are reasonably close to the size of the broadcast variable +1gb.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm completely understanding the end goal (if you are calling collect the limit will the the driver JVM heap), but I'm guessing there is some processing in between. Anyways I'll try and make an example for using RandomRDD in Java tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is:

```
JavaRDD<String> randomStringRDD = RandomRDDs.uniformJavaRDD(jsc, numRows).map((Double d) -> RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(42));
```

Here is a more complete example to test locally:

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test random").setMaster("local");
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    int numRows= 10;//put here how many rows you want
    JavaRDD<String> randomStringRDD = RandomRDDs.uniformJavaRDD(jsc, rows).map((Double d) -> RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(42));

    //display (to use only on small dataset)
    for(String row:randomStringRDD.collect()){
        System.out.println(numRows);
    }
```

There is a small CPU overhead because there is no need to generate the initial set of random numbers, but it takes care of creating the partitions etc.

If avoiding that small overhead is important to you, and you want to generate 1 million rows in 10 partitions, you could try the following:

1. Create an empty rdd via jsc.emptyRDD()
2. Set its partitioning via repartition to create 10 partitions
3. use a mapPartition function to create 1milion/10 partition = 100000 rows per partition. Your RDD is ready.

Side notes:

- Having the RandomRDDs.randomRDD() class exposed would make it simpler, but it is unfortunately not.
- However, RandomRDDs.randomVectorRDD() is exposed, so you could use that one if you need to generate randomized vectors. (but you asked for Strings here so that does not apply).

Comment: These steps from your answer worked for me.  1. Create an empty rdd via jsc.emptyRDD(), 2. Set its partitioning via repartition to create 10 partitions, 3. use a mapPartition function to create 1milion/10 partition = 100000 rows per partition. Your RDD is ready.

Comment: +1, @Julien - I also have similar requirement and using this approach, but the problem is rows per partition is huge so these are causing "OutOfMemory". Because i cant increase number of partitions, beyond a certain number.

Answer (score 1):

The `RandomRDD` class is private to Spark, but we can access the `RandomRDDs` class and to create these. There are some examples in `JavaRandomRDDsSuite.java` (see https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/test/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/random/JavaRandomRDDsSuite.java ). It seems that the java examples all make Double's and the like but we can use this and turn it into strings like so:

```
import static org.apache.spark.mllib.random.RandomRDDs.*;
...
JavaDoubleRDD rdd1 = normalJavaRDD(sc, size, numPartitions);
JavaRDD<String> rdd = rdd1.map(e -> Double.toString(e));
```

That being siad we could use the `randomRDD` function, but it uses class tags which are a bit frustrating to use with Java. (I've created a JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10626 to make an easy Java API for accessing this).